# error when try to get values from object parameter 'object' does not contain a definition for 'employeeID'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I working on a Blazor web application server side written in C#. I have an issue that I can't get values of properties `employee id` and `department code` from object parameter to insert value on table.

I get compile-time error when try to get value for property employee ID - like this:

> Error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'employeeID' and no accessible extension method 'employeeID' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

When I check owner object after break point hit and data passed as below :

```
ValueKind = Object : "{"employeeID":1222,"employeeName":0,"departementCode":"211","jobCode":"1221","ownerType":null,"departementName":"ahmed"}"

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddOwnerFile(object owner)
{
    string ownerfileno = owner.employeeID;
    string departementCode = owner.departementCode;

    var sql = "INSERT INTO Owner (OwnerFileNo, DepartementCode) VALUES ({0}, {1})";

    var rowsAffected = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql, ownerfileno, departementCode);

    return Ok();
}
```

I expected the result would be:

```
ownerfileno=1222
departementCode=211
```

Last updated post

```
var employeeID = owner.GetType()
                      .GetProperties()
                      .First(o => o.Name == "employeeID")
                      .GetValue(owner, null);
```

I try to get the value of `employeeID`, but I get an error at runtime:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no matching element'

How to solve this error, please?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but very important: Your code is open to [SQL injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/). You should use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: so how to pass values on safe can you please help me

Comment: can you please also attach how to get values from object for two properties please without using paramters

Comment: any update about my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `object` type, create the model class for the request body.

```cs
public class Owner
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string DepartementCode { get; set; }
    public string JobCode { get; set; }
    public int? OwnerType { get; set; }
    public string DepartementName { get; set; }
}
```

Amend the `AddOwnerFile` method to receive a parameter with the `Owner` type.

While it always recommends using the [parameterized query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4712037/8017690) to avoid SQL injection. Reference: [Passing the parameter for SQL Queries in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#passing-parameters)

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddOwnerFile([FromBody]Owner owner)
{
    var ownerfileno = new SqlParameter("@employeeID", owner.employeeID);
    var departementCode = new SqlParameter("@departementCode", owner.departementCode);

    var sql = "INSERT INTO Owner (OwnerFileNo, DepartementCode) VALUES (@employeeID, @departementCode)";
    var rowsAffected = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql, ownerfileno, departementCode);

           
    return Ok();
}
```